# Can we say higher entropy leads to better mixing in fluids?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, reversibility

We know irreversibilities always cause the entropy of the system to increase, but if we numerically find entropy generation due to heat transfer/fluid friction in a closed system, can we conclude anything about the mixing of fluid inside system.

Can we say higher entropy leads to better mixing in fluids?

Comment: I think the answer would depend on the specific system...

Comment: By closed system do you mean one that allows energy transfer?

Comment: No, one without energy transfer. Considering only the entropy generated out of two or more fluids mixing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about physical changes leads to entropy changes. So, perception of entropy change is seemed by the change of physically disorder changes. Then, the question can be asked in this way: Does mixing of fluids lead to entropy changes? I know you know the answer and you establish a relation between entropy and mixing of fluids. I think that directly you cannot guess ıf ı change entropy, what happens to the system. Because you should first touch the system to see its behaviours

Comment: This seems to be a popular opinion among my colleagues too. According to them entropy should be dealt with separately as a thermodynamic concept and mixing should be dealt with using fluid dynamics and turbulence models. I am hoping to get further insights from people who may have some experimental experience in dealing with such a system.

Comment: I am currently studying nonlinear dynamics and chaos, so turbulence is examined under the light of this field. As you know that chaos is the aperiodic behaviour of the deterministic systems. So, all of the systems in reality (even if nothing change in this system with respect to time) lead to entropy change.  I think your question is in situations where mixing of fluid increases , the entropy also increases. Entropy always increases if time passes. Maybe I couldnt understand your question :(

Comment: Wow, your field of study sounds interesting! Can you suggest any literature in your field which establishes the fundamentals?